# Linux Centos 6,64 - How do I add a first line in many files from a folder?

Tags: linux, centos

Linux - Centos 6,64

Have a folder with many files .txt in folder /home

file.part.1.txt

file.part.2.txt

file.part.3.txt

etc.

Would like to add in all of them a first line saying "Title", and save the file with their same name and .txt in the end (no change). The quantity of files is random quantity, up to 300 files maximum.

Example:

file.part.1.txt now has:

abc

def

ghi

I need it to be:

Title

abc

def

ghi

And all the other files have different content inside. All of them need to start with "Title" in first line and continue having same content below as they do now from second line onwards.

How can I do this command?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed -i '1s/.*/Title\n&/' file.part.*.txt
```

[image: warning] the `-i` switch edit the content *on the fly*

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, works great. Thanks